# Cannot install Ubuntu One - nowhere to drag to?

Tags: macos, install

I am trying to install Ubuntu One on Mountain Lion. I follow the instructions [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-set-up-ubuntu-one-for-mac-279/) but when I open the DMG file, I can see nowhere obvious to drag it to as below:
[image]
I can run it fine by double clicking, but then I cannot unmount the DMG and Ubuntu One doesn't open when I restart, so it's not really properly installed. Any ideas? (maybe this is a noob question, I'm new to OSX)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just drag the application to your Applications folder. Open Finder and navigate to /Applications and drag and release the icon there.

Comment: Duh, thanks for that explanation. I am loving my new MacBook but the method for installing things is really weird!

Comment: What could be simpler?

Comment: `apt-get install ubuntu-one` !

Comment: To add to this, most dmgs contain the .app bundle and also an alias to your system's Applications folder so you can drag it to there. This one's just the .app, so you have to drag it to Applications yourself.